# I want to be able to simply control the cooling tempreture of a small 40 to 60 millimeter thermoelecrtic cooler

Tags: temperature, peltier

i want to be able to control the cooling temperature of a small 40 to 60millimter TEC.  I understand voltage level plays a part but do not know what voltage level equtes to what temperature on either side of the TEC. Is there a way to ascertain this? Or is there a standard time frame the for the TEC to get to to a required temp using X amount of voltage?

Or am i better to monitor the temp another way and then turn off or hold voltage when the required temp is reached.  I am looking to  get to temperatures between 6 and 14 degrees centigrade. I need a simple, reproducible and cheap way to do this. Thanks

Comment: There are many temperature sensor ICs with resolution of 0.1 deg.C on the market. it should be easy if you know things like Arduino.

Comment: Hey great, thanks for the info. I am a novice to all of this so will look it up

Answer (score 0):

You have to monitor the temperature. There is no "clean" relationship between input voltages and the resulting temperatures -- that'll depend on a number of factors, including the ambient temperature, the thermal mass of the object you're trying to cool, how well it is insulated from the environment, and whether it is generating heat internally.